# react-hook-form react-select in functional component gives warning

Tags: reactjs, react-select, react-hook-form, react-state

I am using react-select 5.2.2, reack-hook-form 7.19.5 and react 17.0.2

Everything is working fine in my component except when I select value in the react-select drop down it throws following warning in the console:

*A component is changing a controlled input to be uncontrolled. This is likely caused by the value changing from a defined to undefined, which should not happen. Decide between using a controlled or uncontrolled input element for the lifetime of the component.*

here is my code for the component

```
const [selectedOption, setSelectedOption] = useState(undefined);
const { data: userAreas } = useQuery(GET_AREAS);

const areasList = userAreas && userAreas.getAreasList.map((obj) => {
    const rObj = {};
    rObj.areaValue = obj;
    rObj.label = obj;
    return rObj;
  });

<Label>Area</Label>
          <Controller
            name="area"
            control={control}
            rules={{ required: 'Area is required' }}
            render={({ field }) => (
              <ReactSelect
                isClearable
                {...field}
                placeholder="Select Your Area"
                value={selectedOption}
                onChange={setSelectedOption}
                options={areasList}
              />
            )}
          />
```

{areasList} is coming from graphql useQuery so initially it is undefined until it receives data in subsequent renders

I have further revised the code to exclude undefined but the warning still occurs. Here is the revised code

```
const { data: userAreas } = useQuery(GET_AREAS);

const areasList = userAreas?.getAreasList.map((obj) => {
    const rObj = {};
    rObj.areaValue = obj;
    rObj.label = obj;
    return rObj;
  }) || [];

<Label>Area</Label>
          <Controller
            name="area"
            control={control}
            rules={{ required: 'Area is required' }}
            render={({ field }) => (
              <ReactSelect
                isClearable
                {...field}
                placeholder="Select Your Area"
                options={areasList}
              />
            )}
          />
```

Comment: Try this: `const { data: userAreas = [] } = useQuery(GET_AREAS);`. Btw there is no need to use `useState` when you're using `react-hook-form`. `react-hook-form` is already handling your state.

Comment: Thank you @Kapobajza regarding useState and I got rid of this now but when I Try this: const { data: userAreas = [] } = useQuery(GET_AREAS)
I receive error on map function here
const areasList = userAreas && userAreas.getAreasList.map((obj) => {

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replacing

```
<Controller
    name="area"
    control={control}
    rules={{ required: 'Area is required' }}
    render={({ field }) => (
        <ReactSelect
           isClearable
           {...field}
           placeholder="Select Your Area"
           options={areasList}
        />
    )}
/>
```

with

```
<Controller
            name="area"
            control={control}
            rules={{ required: 'Area is required' }}
            render={({ field }) => (
              <ReactSelect
                isClearable
                value={field.value}
                onChange={field.onChange}
                ref={field.ref}
                placeholder="Select Your Area"
                options={areasList}
              />
            )}
          />
```

fixed my problem.

Comment: Removing the `name` `prop` seems to be the solution, does it make sense? is all good with the `control` after that?

Answer (score 0):

you are changing uncontrollable component to controllable

check this [documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components)

the value is undefined at the first render so it is uncontrollable then the value is changed and your component became controllable

the value attribute should be like this

`selectedOption ?? <empty data here>`

Comment: Thank you @ozan-mudul but the problem is when we cross the selected value to select any other option, react-select sets the value to null which throws this warning again and if I use selectedOption ?? <empty data here> it does not allow to cross the current selection and select any other option

Comment: hmm can you try to put it in a loader so that areasList gets its value after that you can render this component?

Comment: I have modified code so that in case of undefined it should have empty [] but the warning is still there

Comment: hmm, have you tried async select? https://react-select.com/async maybe that's the case

Comment: Seems to be the issue with internal state management of react-hook-form controller because it is setting value to null when we select any option in the drop down. This is obvious when I debug using react dev tools and see the state of value

Comment: I don't know how Graphql works but check this out, it may help you. I prepared a sandbox for you https://codesandbox.io/s/weathered-wood-suye2?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Thank you @ozan-mudul I am doing everything similar except my options are coming from the database through GraphQL API

Comment: put your options into empty state then set the state when you got your data from graphql this should work

Comment: Already tested this and debugged state changes. On first render everything behaves like what we are expecting but as soon as I select any option, value is set to null automatically rather than being loaded from state as an empty state. May be by the react-hook-form itself

Comment: I really don't know how graphql works but I found a working example and tried to implement your components https://codesandbox.io/s/graphql-apollo-cliente-countries-api-integration-forked-h38nw?file=/src/App.tsx I hope it helps